# Authenticate with Pin TweetSharp c#

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

How can I get Acess Token and Access Token Secret in C# when I alredy have the pin?

Can't find anything about this.

This is my code until now:

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService(global.cKey, global.cSecret);
        OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();
        Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
        Process.Start(uri.ToString());
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the TwitterService.GetAccessToken method providing the request token you already retrieved above, and the 'pin' as the 'verifier' argument;

```
// verifier = a string containing the pin code
OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

The object returned contains the access token key and secret as separate properties.